# correct the card info or try a different card in google api

Tags: google-apis-explorer

while starting free trial in Google Cloud Platform, I correctly put my card information several times with several cards, but, it again and again says "correct the card info or try a different card". The following image shows the issue.

[image]

I can't understand the issue. Could someone bring some light into it please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved this?